# Unwrapping a ring of faces

Tags: uv

I have a mesh with round face(picture1). I just wondered if i could unwrap this round face as straight as in the second picture. Is it possible ?

[image]

This is how i want to unrwap it;
[image]

Comment: It is not round face, it's a mesh composed of ring of faces. It can be unwrapped to be as shown on the second screenshot but there will be at least 2 islands

Comment: @MrZak, you are right. but you got what i wanted to say. And thank you for the answer! "Follow Active Quads - Even" did it :)